# Set Value To Zero In Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In my app I use the following code to set a value of an array to zero:

```
 [[records objectAtIndex:prizenotify] setValue:nil forKey:@"marbles"];
    NSError *error;
    [_managedObjectContext save:&error]; //Save
```

But, It crashes my code. Am I coding this correctly? Marbles is an NSNumber.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of crash do you have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[records objectAtIndex:prizenotify] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0] forKey:@"marbles"];
```

Or in modern Objective-C:

```
[records[prizenotify] setValue:@0 forKey:@"marbles"];
```

Comment: It Still Crashes Without Warning. This is My Current Code: `-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        
       
       
        NSLog(@"It Works");
    
        
        [[records objectAtIndex:prizenotify] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0] forKey:@"marbles"];
        [[records objectAtIndex:prizenotify] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"prizereached"];

        NSError *error;
        [_managedObjectContext save:&error]; //Save 
        
        
    }
    
}
` Thanks!

Comment: Looks fine. What is the error message that you get after crashing?

Comment: There isn't any, it just receives a sigbart without anything on the debugger. It goes straight to (gdb).

Comment: Click on gdb's "continue" button (icon should look a bit like this: "||>") a couple of times and it should print out an exception or the like. Anyway, I'm on the leave. The code that you posted in the comment looks fine. Something else must be the cause, I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to set a nil-esque value, you can use `[NSNull null]` to insert null/nil values into a collection class like NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that `[records objectAtIndex:prizenotify]` object is a NSMutableDictionary.**

To be sure, test :

```
[[((NSDictionary*)[records objectAtIndex:prizenotify]) mutableCopy] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0] forKey:@"marbles"];
```

if this one works, the problem is that you just have a NSDictionary (not mutable).

If you have a NSMutableDictionary for sure :

- If you want to set the value to zero, call :

  [[records objectAtIndex:prizenotify] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0] forKey:@"marbles"];
- If you want to delete the 'marbles' key from the dictionary, call :

  [[records objectAtIndex:prizenotify] removeObjectForKey:@"marbles"];

Answer (score 0):

Although I would choose Sean's solution (`[NSNull null]`) as the simplest solution, there is also the [NSPointerArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPointerArray_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html) class (which specifically answers your question). Here's the overview:

> NSPointerArray is a mutable collection modeled after NSArray but it
>   can also hold NULL values, which can be inserted or extracted (and
>   which contribute to the object’s count). Moreover, unlike traditional
>   arrays, you can set the count of the array directly. In a garbage
>   collected environment, if you specify a zeroing weak memory
>   configuration, if an element is collected it is replaced by a NULL
>   value.